# Free PDF viewer that opens several pdf files in different tabs

Tags: linux, open-source, ubuntu, pdf-viewer

I want a pdf-viewer that can opens several pdf files in different tabs (single window) for **Ubuntu** 14.04.

(I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and `evince` is pre-installed but it opens pdf files in different windows not in single window and different tabs)

**If open more than 1 pdf files than it should be open in single window but in different tabs.**

Following are expected:

- Recommended free & open-source
- Only to view pdf files.
- No Editing required.
- Lightweight (consume less ram & cpu usage)

Comment: @ṧнʊß No gratis for only no-cost but I am talking about [**freedom**](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.html) / [**libre**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software#Definition)

Comment: Never mind - Izzy [has done it](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1038/what-to-do-with-the-free-software-tag). Please add an answer there showing your views :)

Comment: didn't read comments before editing - rolledback until that thread is done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of options:

1. **qpdfview** - install with `sudo apt-get install qpdfview` and it is free, lightweight and works well out of the box, you can even restrict the cache size in the preferences.

[image: qpdfview]
[image: preferences]

2. Google Chrome - you can open pdf files in separate tabs, it's free & you may well have it already - not just a pdf viewer but if it is installed and you have issues installing anything else it will do the job.

Answer (score 4):

If you're focus is lightweight / minimalist, you might like [Apvlv](https://github.com/naihe2010/apvlv), which is an free, open source, tabbed PDF viewer for Linux that behaves like Vim:

[image]